# Parsing rendered React component

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React, and struggling with this.

I have a React component which renders into this object element:
[image]

Since this is an [object], I can't figure out how to convert it to a number or a string (tried toString(), Number(), parseInt() nothing works), is there a way to "parse" the generated  after the component has been rendered and assign it to a variable?

I need that number either as a string or a number.

Comment: What's the use case here? Reading your own output is an unusual thing to do. Surely you can access that number before it's rendered.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, however with no success. It is a Drizzle Component to query Ethereum to return the number. The returned number is an object. I need it to be a number or a string to pass it as a prop for another function that sends a transaction, and the ETH calculated is based on that number. So far all my attempts to get it from the object failed.

Comment: The reason you can't parse the rendered output is because you're not supposed to. There is almost certainly a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: use state or props and parse this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to switch from Drizzle back to pure React. The issue with transforming an object into a number has remained unresolved.